# Visual studio 2015 not compile changes c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

from some time visual c++ compiler not compiling my code, I tried to do things that are there: [Visual Studio 2013 C++ not compiling changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698928/visual-studio-2013-c-not-compiling-changes)

Cleaning soultion works in my case, but after compilation i must do it again and so always. I saw also Build solution options and build configuration and there are OK. I moved project, delete execute file but it also not helped me.

What I can do to fix it? :(

Comment: Make sure the object directory is not a subdirectory of the TEMP directory?

Comment: @stijn How I can check this?

Comment: Project properties->intermediate directory or something like that. But I'm not sure this is the problem here, you don't provide a lot fo information.

Comment: @stijn I have here: "<different options>"

Comment: You should learn to use the tools first. It shows that because you are looking at the options for multiple configurations and/or platforms at the same time. Select only one of those.

Comment: Ok, now it works, thanks!